# How to migrate inflight workflows from Activiti to Alfresco process service?

Tags: migration, workflow, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I wanted to migrate workflows from Activiti BPM to Alfresco process service. Is there a way to migrate all my in flight workflows with all InProgress user tasks to Alfresco process service?

Please advice if there is any tool available to do this migration or any other best suitable way available for this migration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is anyone came across with such scenario of migrating workflows from one application to another?